# How to unit test kotlin coroutine with nested suspended functions

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

Below is the piece of code that I am trying to unit test. The code before `async(CommonPool)` the first suspending function is testable but after that, the tests keeps on failing. I tried using `runBlocking` but cannot test the nested suspended async function anyway.

```
interface Listener {
        fun onLoading(user: User?)

        fun onSuccess(user: User)
}

execute(listener: Listener) {

        listener.onLoading(null)
        val service = UserService.getInstance(context, "someurl")
        val database = UserDatabase.getInstance(context)

        launch(UI) {

            val user = async(CommonPool) {
                userDatabase.getUser()
            }.await()

            listener.onLoading(user)

            val response = service.getUsersSelf(oauthToken).await()

            async(CommonPool) {database.saveUser(userResponse.data.user)}.await()

            val user = async(CommonPool) {database.getUser()}.await()

            listener.onSuccess(user)
        }
    }
```

Below is my unit test, I am using mockito for mocking my listener and checking the number of interactions.

```
@Test
    fun execute() {
        runBlocking {
            userDatabase.saveUser(user)

            val listener = mock(GetUser.Listener::class.java)

            getUser.execute(listener)

            verify(listener, times(1)).onLoading(null) // Success

            verify(listener, times(1)).onLoading(user) // Fails

            verify(listener, times(1)).onSuccess(user) // Fails
        }
    }
```

But the last two `verify` test fails. Can anyone help me out with testing?

Answer (score 1):

Your `execute` is a fire-and-forget function. If this was done with threads, it would be `Thread { <code> }.start()` and completely letting go of the reference to the thread. The only thing you have left is the `Listener` instance that will get notified when the call completes — but not in the case of an error.

While I doubt it's a good approach to using coroutines, which are all about *eliminating* callback interfaces like your `Listener`, if you know this approach is good for you, then the listener is your only handle to the happenings in the coroutine you launched.

Therefore you must implement your unit-testing logic inside the listener. Given the absence of a failure callback, you may wait for some limited time for the methods to get called. One approach:

```
fun execute() {
    val latch = CountDownLatch(3)
    runBlocking {
        val x = object : Listener {

            override fun onLoading(user: User?) {
                if (user == null) {
                    require(latch.count == 3L)
                    latch.countDown()
                } else {
                    require(latch.count == 2L)
                    latch.countDown()
                }
            }

            override fun onSuccess(user: User) {
                require (latch.count == 1L)
                latch.countDown()
            }
        }
    }
    require(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the UI Dispatcher with `Dispatchers.Unconfined` at test time using dependency injection. This test succeeds:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    var result = false
    GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
        async(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
            sleep(1000)
            result = true
        }.await()
    }
    assertTrue(result)
}
```